# Clojure code to analyze clojure code

Tags: clojure

I'd like to analyze a file of foreign clojure code.  I'm currently using `clojure.tools.reader` to read all the forms:

```
(require '[clojure.tools.reader :as reader])

(defn read-all-forms [f]
  (let [rdr (indexing-push-back-reader (slurp f))
        EOF (Object.)
        opts {:eof EOF}]
    (loop [ret []]
      (let [form (reader/read opts rdr)]
        (if (= EOF form)
          ret
          (recur (conj ret form)))))))
```

This generally works, except when it encounters a double-colon keyword that refers to an aliased ns.  Example:

```
(ns foo
  (:require [foo.bar :as bar]))

::bar/baz
```

Fails with:

`ExceptionInfo Invalid token: ::bar/baz`

Is there a way to use clojure.tools.reader to read the file and resolve keywords like this?  Am I supposed to somehow keep track of the `*alias-map*` myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tools.reader uses `clojure.tools.reader/*alias-map*` if it's bound, otherwise it uses `(ns-aliases *ns*)` to resolve aliases. So if you have auto-resolved keywords in your file, you will need to use one of those approaches to allow auto-resolved aliases to be resolved.

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up doing `(binding [reader/*alias-map* identity] (reader/read ...))`.  Hopefully that's not too much of an abuse.  (For my purpose, I don't need accurate alias-map resolving.)